# Select Multiple popup

Tags: excel, vba, salesforce

I was working on an Excel project, but I come across an annoying issue. 
The picklist is from Salesforce multi picklist field.
XL connector connects excel to salesforce.

When I double click this particular column, a pop up opens us asking if I want to select multiple.
How do I remove this data validation? 
I have tried clearing the whole column data validation, cleared all conditional formatting and even clear button to erase all, without any success. 
I have even deleted the column but it keeps coming back just like my EX

It looks simple but I give up.
If anyone could help me it will be very helpful.

[image: Excel Popup]

Answer (score 0):

Goto **Application Settings** and tick the checkbox **Ignoring Picklist Validation on Save**

Use this option when you want the picklist validation to be ignored when saving the data back to your environment in runtime.